# Fluentd Multiple regex named Captures

Tags: regex, fluentd

Can we concatenate multiple regex named captures?

I'm trying to use the following regex in fluentd conf file to get both "User" & "Serial_Number" but could only get the first name(User).

td-agent.conf:

```
<source>
   type tail
   format /(?<User>(?<=user:).*?(?=\]))(?<Serial_Number>(?<=sn:).*?(?=\]))/
   tag xxxxxx
   path /app/logs/xxxx.log
   pos_file /var/log/td-agent/xxxx_rolling.pos
</source>
```

Log File:

```
Jul24,11:20:17 TID:6 INFO [user:weblogic] [sn:088039] [dur:806ms] {***message}
```

I'm new to this regex format in fluentD and would appreciate any help in this issue.

-Praveen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Concatenating" in this case is not necessary, you just need to allow some arbitrary nbumber of arbitrary characters in-between the first capture group and the second one.

You are better off with negated character classes, and you need to let any characters between the user and the sn:

```
/(?<User>(?<=user:)[^]]*)\].*?(?<Serial_Number>(?<=sn:)[^]]*)?\]/
                   ^^^^  ^^^^^                         ^^^^  ^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eB2pG9/6)

The `[^]]*` negated character class will match 0 or more characters other then `]` and `.*` will match 0 or more characters other than a newline.

If you need to match the subtexts in any order, you may also use

```
/^(?=.*(?:(?<User>(?<=user:)[^]]*)))(?=(?:.*(?<Serial_Number>(?<=sn:)[^]]*))?)/
```

See [the second demo](https://regex101.com/r/eB2pG9/5)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I would like to capture just the word 'weblogic' and '088039' with those tags. The reason I am trying to capture names is that my log may not be in a particular format. It can have error code in between user & sn incase of any error message.

Comment: If there may be newlines in between, you may use `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?`. Does it work?

Comment: Please also check my update and the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eB2pG9/4) here.

Comment: Thanks it worked for the lines which are in that order, but it can not match anything on the other line. Can we have a common regex for both the lines below?                      2015-07-27 14:39:23,720 TID:4 ERROR o.p.e.r.a.t.i.o.n.s-102 - [user:weblogic]  [dur:1ms] [code:507] Invalid value: Address should be of valid format(xx:xx:)- {*****Message} 
2015-07-27 14:39:23,720 TID:6 INFO  o.p.e.r.a.t.i.o.n.s-83 - [user:weblogic] [sn:088039] [type:xxx] [dest:xxxxxxxx] [rpc:xxxxxx] [dur:806ms] {*************Message}

Comment: I hope it is working now, I made the sn part optional.